# Can i specify multiple countries in one torrc file, and if yes, what chronological order is used?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

I counted about 250 different land codes.

The default one is {us}

So my question is if i can specify more than one for each torrc file?

So that it for example looks like this:

{us}, {tr}, {va}, {ve}

This make an additional questions comes up.

I wonder if it for example use the Exit Nodes from left to right.

First time open up the window, does it use {us} Exit Nodes.

Second time open up the window, does it use {tr} Exit Nodes.

Or is that random what chronological order it uses?

Im confused by this an need some clarification

Answer (score 1):

Tor by default does not limit the exit nodes (the `ExitNodes` option is unset). When you specify exit nodes with the `ExitNodes` option, there is no ordering. Instead it simply chooses an exit as it normally does (randomly according to the [path spec](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/plain/path-spec.txt)), but excludes any relays not included in this set. See tor's `choose_good_exit_server_general()` for reference.